# How to retrieve SSIS Packages and the associated tables from SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-agent

I'm currently working on a documentation project related to SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) packages that are executed through SQL Server Agent jobs. In other words, I want to create a mapping that indicates which tables are accessed and manipulated by each SSIS package.

I have created scripts to retrieve the list of SSIS packages executed by these jobs, and I also have a comprehensive list of all the tables in each database within the SQL Server instance.

Here's the specific information I have:

1. List of SSIS Packages: I have successfully retrieved a list of all SSIS packages that are executed through SQL Server Agent jobs. This list includes package names and descriptions where available.
2. List of All Tables: I have generated a comprehensive list of all tables present in each database within the SQL Server instance. This list includes table names and column details.

Now that I have both the list of SSIS packages and the list of tables, I need to associate each SSIS package with the tables it utilizes. Despite having these two sets of information, I encountered challenges when attempting to combine the results of these queries to get the required mapping between SSIS packages and the list of tables. I'm seeking guidance on how to efficiently associate tables with SSIS packages, preferably using SQL queries or scripts. Thank you for your help!

Comment: This is a common requirement and non trivial. Assuming all tables are defined explicitly in the package (not in variables or runtime)  you can use an external script (i.e. Powershell) to open each package XML and match it to each table in your list. That at least tells you what tables are in package. It doesn't tell you direction, To do anything else requires sophisticated shredding of the package XML

Comment: Well the SSIS packages are .dtsx XML files, and the format is documented, [MS-DTSX: Data Transformation Services Package XML File Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/sql_data_portability/ms-dtsx/235600e9-0c13-4b5b-a388-aa3c65aec1dd), so have you done anything to parse the files yet?

Comment: @Nick.Mc I have developed a Python script designed to parse XML files and extract table names from them. However, I am encountering a challenge due to the diverse formats in which these tables can be present within SSIS packages. These variations include scenarios where the SSIS package may consist of a Python script, lack an Execute SQL task, or involve a direct connection to a flat file followed by an OLE DB Destination. I am seeking a robust solution that can account for all of these possibilities and ensure accurate extraction of table names from SSIS packages.

Comment: There is no robust solution, you need to code for every specific case. Note that Purview supports extracting SSIS lineage. I believe it does it by interrogating the runtime logs. Logs might give you a better idea of what is actually executing.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/purview/how-to-lineage-sql-server-integration-services

Comment: But for the explicit requirement of identifying what tables are in packages, as I said, I did this by _first_ identifying all table names then searching for them in the XML, rather than trying to identify what is a table from source code. Having said that Python is probably your best bet for cracking source code. Depending on how keen you are you could try an ML model to crack table names out of source code but you will likely get a lot of incorrect answers

Comment: @Nick.Mc, I have successfully extracted the tables from the Execute SQL task step. I am now focused on enhancing the robustness of this process. My current efforts involve a comprehensive examination of the SSIS package properties. I am actively working to establish a systematic approach for capturing a broader range of tables within these packages. This entails a detailed analysis to discern patterns in how tables are stored and managed.